# How to determine which if statement the else belongs to?

Tags: java, if-statement, semantics

I wrote the following code and confused myself.

```
if(condition1)
    if(condition2){
        doStuff()
    }
else {
    doOtherStuff();
}
```

When it's indented like this it looks like the else belongs to the condition1 if. But if we change some whitespace, it looks like it's part of the condition2 if like so:

```
if(condition1)
    if(condition2){
        doStuff()
    } else {
        doOtherStuff();
    }
```

So which does it belong to? I put in brackets for the condition1 as to be more clear, but which of these is correct?

Comment: use explicit braces on both (all) if's

Comment: Don't avoid optional curly brackets

Comment: The general rule of thumb is this.The else always belongs to the  enclosing if(nearest if)

Comment: How hard can it be to try it out before asking the world?

Comment: If you have an IDE, it will indent code for you to make the nesting obvious.

Answer (score 3):

It belongs to the *condition2* `if` statement.

The reason for this is that since your *condition1* if statement **doesn't** wrap with brackets (`{}`) it's body, it's assumed that it's body contains **one single** statement. Looking at the *condition2* `if` statement (including the `else`), it's a valid (`if/else`) statement and therefore it's considered as one-piece.

If you want to make the `else` belong to the outer `if`, you have to wrap the body of the first one in brackets.

```
if (condition1) {
    if (condition2) {

    }
} else {
   doOtherStuff();
}
```

In general, it's good practice **always** to wrap the bodies of conditional structures and loops with brackets (`{}`) (even they contain a single nested statement), because the code gets more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

It belongs to `condition2`. If you want to belong it to `condition1` you have to use parentheses

```
if(condition1) {
    if(condition2){
        doStuff()
    }
} else {
    doOtherStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it matches with if which ever was the last one i.e. your inner if. If you want else part to be associated with outer if, you should use braces explicitely like:

```
if(condition1) {
    if(condition2){
        doStuff()
    } 
} else {
    doOtherStuff();
}
```